# What kind of client/server protocols python supports out of the box?

Tags: python, client-server

Without installing third party libraries, what kind of [Client/Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) protocols Python supports out of the box ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **Basic Web Protocols**:

  - Downloading from http, ftp and file: with [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), but note that in python 3 that `urllib.urlopen` has moved to `urllib2.urlopen` and is deprecated from python 2.6
  - Downloading from https and http with basic proxy and authentication support with [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)
  - http with [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), and server modules [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html), [`SimpleHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) and [`CGIHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html), but note that the servers have been moved to [`http.server`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/http.server.html) in python 3
  - ftp uploading/downloading with [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)
  - telnet with [`telnetlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html)
- **Mail Protocols**:

  - imap with [`imaplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html)
  - pop3 with [`poplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html)
  - smtp with [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) and [`smtpd`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html)
- **XML-RPC**:

  - XML RPC client with [`xmlrpclib`](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) and server modules [`SimpleXMLRPCServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) and [`DocXMLRPCServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/docxmlrpcserver.html), but the servers have been moved to [`xmlrpc.server`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/xmlrpc.server.html) in python 3
- **News Reading Protocols**:

  - NNTP with [`nntplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/nntplib.html)